# How to get VS to use specific diff tool when using git for SCM?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When using VS, if I do a comparison on a non-text file when comparing to the previous one, VS just says that `One or both of these files are not text files and cannot be opened in the comparison window.  ... The contents of the two files are different.`

I've setup my git environment so that it uses specific scripts when comparing images, but how do I get VS to either respect that or specify some other method for telling VS to use my scripts?

Comment: I had the same issue today with a quite old version of VS 2017. After updating to the newest version (15.9.59) the comparison works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Git allows you to configure both a "merge tool" and a "diff tool" via it's config files (local repo-specific config at [your repo]/.git/config and global at c:\users[youruser].gitconfig).

For example here is the relevant section of my config

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BCompare.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
    path = C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\BCompare.exe
```

You can find the git config documentation [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Note that there are some tools that are supported "out of the box". If you use one of those you don't have to provide a custom path to the executable like I have above.

Once you have configured your diff/merge tools VS should respect these settings and launch the diff in your tool of choice.

Comment: Should or does? I've not used the git difftool yet, but I have setup git diff. Wasn't sure of the difference between the two.

Comment: My visual studio (2017) launches diffs in beyond compare, as I have set up in the config. I never made any changes in Visual Studio to make this happen. A diff tool is exactly what it suggests, an external program that will take over the diff/merge. Did it not work for you?

Comment: I have never used any form of custom scripts like you suggest though.

Answer (score 0):

Should or does? I've not used the git difftool yet, but I have setup git diff. Wasn't sure of the difference between the two.

Comment: Stupid UI. Must have pressed the wrong button and the app can't delete it.